# How to schedule a server call using FCM job dispatcher that executes everyday?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-job-dispatcher

I've read that in order to optimize device battery I have to use FCM job dispatcher. My requirement is to send data to servers via a simple POST request to my servers everyday(once). Now should I use FCM dispatcher or Alarm Manager. If I have use FCM dispatcher how could I use it since it has  only set trigger().

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android). They didn't have documentation for everyday periodic tasks.

Here is the code they have given:

```
Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
    // the JobService that will be called
    .setService(MyJobService.class)
    // uniquely identifies the job
    .setTag("my-unique-tag")
    // one-off job
    .setRecurring(false)
    // don't persist past a device reboot
    .setLifetime(Lifetime.UNTIL_NEXT_BOOT)
    // start between 0 and 60 seconds from now
    .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 60))
    // don't overwrite an existing job with the same tag
    .setReplaceCurrent(false)
    // retry with exponential backoff
    .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
    // constraints that need to be satisfied for the job to run
    .setConstraints(
        // only run on an unmetered network
        Constraint.ON_UNMETERED_NETWORK,
        // only run when the device is charging
        Constraint.DEVICE_CHARGING
    )
    .setExtras(myExtrasBundle)
    .build();
```

How could I use this code for scheduling a task that executes periodically?

Comment: "My requirement is to send data to servers via a simple POST request to my servers everyday at 12 AM" -- I do not think that you have that degree of control over the timing.

Comment: @CommonsWare Then I have execute once in everyday. Is that possible?

Comment: "Every day" should be possible with Firebase Job Dispatcher. It is definitely possible with `JobScheduler`, `AlarmManager`, or libraries that wrap around those (e.g., Evernote's `android-job` library). However, "every day at 12am" would be a problem.